# django and netbeans?

Tags: python, django, netbeans, ide

I use netbeans for all of my Linux development (C/C++, Php, Python, Symfony). I am now learning django, and wondered if I could use netbeans as the IDE. I cant seem to find a Django plugin for netbeans.

Is there one?. If no when is one planned?

Worst case scenario, I'll have to use another IDE (I really dont want to learn another IDE) - But, If so, what do you guys use for django development?

Comment: you can use django with netbeans, using the same plugin for python and creating a new project with existing sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is Python and Django support from the [built-in **Python** plug-in](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall)  (in short simply get *any* NetBeans 6.9 or more recent, go to menu Update... > Search "Python" > Install).

There is also a [NetBeans-Django](http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-django/) additional project going on but pretty dead for a while.

Comment: If you are running Netbeans 7.x, you might need to install the development version of the plugin.  Add http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz as an update center in your plugins manager per the instructions in [this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic37805-0-asc-15.html).

Answer (score 3):

Currently, NetBeans support for Django is limited. The [last posting that I could find, from 1 January 2010](http://blogs.oracle.com/matheus/entry/django_in_netbeans_coming_soon) and says that Django support is coming in NetBeans 7.0. I wouldn't be surprised if a few Python improvements in support of this make it into 6.10 due out in August 2010, but 7.0, due for 2010Q4 or 2011Q1, should have some Django support. If it's half as good as Ruby on Rails support, it'll be slick.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans doesn't have a django plugin that I know of. Eclipse's pydev plugin is decent, I typically use any ol' editor and bpython.

I've heard great things about wingware and intellij's new python ide is pretty good.