# Django Text Markup Editors

Tags: python, django, markup, semantic-markup, markup-extensions

Can you suggest some good django-specific text-markup editors?

Comment: Could you clarify?  Are you looking for editors for development, or WYSIWYG-style in-page editors for site content, or... what?

Comment: I'm not looking for an IDE, as the direction of answers seems to have taken. I'm looking for something that you would find in the admin side of the site when editing a textarea.

Answer (score 2):

As for WYSIWYG in-page editor, there are not too many alternatives: wymeditor (used by djangocms), tinymce, ckeditor. I prefer tinymce because there is an easy integration with django-filebrowser.

btw you can find better answers than mine in SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+wysiwyg

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of wymeditor. When giving administrative access to non-technical people, they have great difficult using it (mostly because they tend to paste formatted text into it, and it accepts it instead of forcing it go to plaintext first). Then formatting becomes all messed up across the site...

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the RAM:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) with [Pydev](http://pydev.org) and [Django Editor](http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/)
- NetBeans 7, which is due out 2010 Q4 (see [django and netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971309/django-and-netbeans) for more info)

A bit lighter:

- [Wing](http://www.wingware.com/)
- [JetBrains PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (Guido's favorite, but at $100 for the personal edition and no free major upgrades, it's a bit steep)

Lightest:

- Most Linux distros' text editors (I know that KWrite, Kate, and gedit all have syntax highlighting for Django templates

Comment: PyCharm isn't Guido's favorite unless something has changed. He basically said that he likes it for the debugger, is offended by its handling of `:` in dictionary literals and will probably stick with emacs+pdb for all but intense debugging: [reference](http://www.google.com/buzz/gvanrossum/CGh9MoWU53V/I-tried-PyCharm-today-Now-I-am-mostly-an).

Comment: While we're in the land of IDEs, might look at [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/).  At the time I tried it, I liked it, but it was too slow loading the project files at program startup to be useful to me (but that was over sshfs at the time, so can't really blame Eric on that)

Comment: @aaronasterling I recall hearing on #python that Guido favored it; then again, we might want to take the man's word for it. emacs = an acquired taste, like smoking (it ultimately is harmful because it makes you hate everything less full-featured)

Comment: That is definitely true about emacs. I noticed that I was already feeling crippled using anything else before I even knew about the mark ring. I can't imagine using anything else for even a day after having used it for thirty years like Guido has.

Comment: @aaronasterling I've refused to let myself be spoiled by emacs because I know there will be many days I'll be without it. So I've never used it and I don't intend to.