# Need Advice on ide choice for Django Development

Tags: python, django, ide

I've been programming with PHP for about 6 years, and wanna start developing on django.

Now I have some questions for you django pros. I've been using PHPDesigner for about a year, because I could never be relieved and code well with eclipse/aptana/similar. I just feel weird with them.

I also have used Komodo Edit and gmate (gedit hack+plugins to make gedit look and work like textmate) on linux.

Of course this question has been answered here before, but most answers were either out of date or were the applications which i'm not feeling comfortable.

So, what IDE would you suggest ? Free solutions would be cool, but price is not a criteria here.

p.s: some documentations / suggestions like "django for noobs" would also be appreciated.

Edit: I'm using Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It has a great built-in django support, and continuously improved with new features.

Comment: I second PyCharm. I switched to it from Coda and the fact that is has built in support for django makes it a definite winner for me.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I stick with [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).  It [does have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971309/django-and-netbeans) support for Python and Django, as well as your other languages (PHP, Java, etc).  It's nice and quick, and is quite configurable.  And it's open source.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of good choices.  What you should mostly look for is a good IDE for Python, although support for Django templates has some benefits too.

Personally I use Eclipse plus PyDev, with a vim plugin.  This way I can keep my favorite editor, and get the benefits of simple code refactoring, instant code navigation (ctrl-click on a method call to jump to its definition) and syntax checking while you type.  IMHO the biggest benefit of an IDE is the ability to interactive debugging - setting breakpoints, line-by-line execution, etc.

Netbeans is also a great choice.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to quickly dissolve into a which editor is better discussion. The reality is that with django's "testserver"  your choice of editor / ide become less important. The IDE does not have to be tightly bound to the running code with django. We use eclipse w/ pydev here at work almost exclusively. A few developers have jEdit.

Really though, the final answer should be, code with whatever you code best in.

Comment: Actually exactly that's why I've mentioned which editors/IDEs I code best in.

Comment: As long as an editor has python syntax highlighting you'll do perfectly fine. As for your documentation question, the django tutorial is a great place to start (once you understand the basics of python)

Comment: Indeed, e.g eclipse for PHP or Aptana also has same features, but sometimes you just don't feel the comfortability you need.